# adding values to a hash if key exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, dictionary, ruby-on-rails-4

i have some data that looks like this:

```
[["2000475042", "1"], [{:match_day_uid=>"2000475042", :external_player_uid=>"88", :external_team_uid=>"1", :player_display_name=>"Cardin Constance", :team_display_name=>"Alpha Monkeys", :score=>33}, ...]]

[["2000475042", "2"], [{:match_day_uid=>"2000475042", :external_player_uid=>"253", :external_team_uid=>"2", :player_display_name=>"Cochran Callahan", :team_display_name=>"Ghost Commandos", :score=>169}, ...]]

...
```

The data is grouped by two ids - `match_day_uid` and `external_team_uid` in the first array and goes on to list each instance of matching data in the second array.

I want to make a new hash with this data where the grouping is by `match_day_uid` with data for each team inside a hash that is keyed by `external_team_uid`.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
def output
  output = {}
  data_stream.each { |identifiers, data|
    output[identifiers[0]] = {  
      :external_team_uid  => identifiers[1],
      :team_score         => data.map { |p| p[:score] }.inject(:+),
      :data               => [ data ]
    }  
  }  
  output
end
```

and the output is 'right' - i can call `output["2000475042"]` and get the data, which looks like this:

```
{:external_team_uid=>"3", :team_score=>1026, :data=>[ <all the data here> ]}
```

but there's only one team - which means that the value for the key is being overwritten each time, and i'm left with the data for whatever team was last iterated through.

How can I get the data for ALL the teams as a value for one key (which is the match_day_id)?

**Desired Output**

```
:match_days => {
  :match_day_1 = [
    '3' => {:external_team_uid=>"3", :team_score=>1026, :data=>[ <all the data here> ]},
    '4' => {:external_team_uid=>"4", :team_score=>2222, :data=>[ <all the data here> ]},
    etc...
  ],
  :match_day_1 = [
    '3' => {:external_team_uid=>"3", :team_score=>415, :data=>[ <all the data here> ]},
    '4' => {:external_team_uid=>"4", :team_score=>9644, :data=>[ <all the data here> ]},
    etc...
  ]
  ...
}
```

Comment: Do you need somethng like this: `{ ..., :team_score=>[ 1026, 100, etc ]`, or what?

Comment: have updated to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def convert(data_stream)
output = {}
  data_stream.each { |identifiers, data|
  output[identifiers[0]] ||= []
    output[identifiers[0]] << {  
      :external_team_uid  => identifiers[1],
      :team_score         => data.map { |p| p[:score] }.inject(:+),
      :data               => [ data ]
    }  
  }  
  output
end
```

Comment: use each_with_object to avoid temp var